# Python Global Variable Not Defined - Declared inside Class

Tags: python, selenium, testing

I've seen a lot of questions on global variables, but for some reason I still can't get mine to work.

Here is my scenario -  I have my individual test cases and a separate python script that includes different functions for the various error messages you can get in the application I'm testing.  If one of the validations fails, I want the function to increment a failure variable and then the main test script will check to see if it's a pass or fail.

```
class ErrorValidations:
    failures = 0
    def CheckforError1(driver):
        global failures
        try:
            if error1.is_displayed():
                failures += 1

    def CheckforError2(driver):
        global failures
        try:
            if error2.is_displayed():
                failures += 1

    def CheckforError3(driver):
        global failures
        try:
            if error3.is_displayed():
                failures += 1
```

This is a heavily edited example of where the validations get used:

```
from functionslist import ErrorValidations


def test(driver, browser, test_state):

    _modules = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="navlink"]')

    for i in _modules:
        i.click()

        ErrorValidations.CheckforError1(driver)
        ErrorValidations.CheckforError2(driver)
        ErrorValidations.CheckforError3(driver)

        if ErrorValidations.failures > 0:
            driver.report.AppendToReport( i.text, "The " + i.text + "page was not able to load without errors.", "fail", "")
        else:
            driver.report.AppendToReport( i.text,  "The " + i.text + "page was able to load without errors.", "pass", "")
```

The test is not properly incrementing the failures variable and I get the error: name 'failures' is not defined, but I'm not sure where else to define it.

Comment: Please fix indentation. Is this is all in once class or just the failures variable? It is unclear from your post

Comment: If I'm reading the first code snippet right, failures is not a global variable but a class variable. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Indentation updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring a class attribute 'failures', not a global, within the ErrorValidations

Instead of using global failures try:

```
class ErrorValidations:
    failures = 0

    def CheckforError1(driver):
        try:
            if error1.is_displayed():
                ErrorValidations.failures += 1
```

A true global would be declared outside of the class